# restart function in batch file

Tags: python, variables, batch-file

well... i have a batch file which calls a python script. the thing is that the way i create the batch file, after using once the py script it terminates. How is it possible to make it start over?

```
echo.
echo.
set /P IP=test py: 
test %IP%
choice /M "Press Y to restart or N to stop" /c YN
```

I mean can i declare a variable for the following part:

```
set /P IP=test py:
test %IP%
```

So i can use something like

```
GOTO var
```

and if the user hit no it will terminate the session.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

two ways to check a variable.

```
set /P MyVar=test py:
IF "%MyVar%"=="" (ECHO MyVar is NOT defined) ELSE (ECHO MyVar IS defined)
```

or the second but need `enableextensions`

```
setlocal enableextensions
set /P MyVar=test py:
IF DEFINED MyVar (ECHO MyVar IS defined) ELSE (ECHO MyVar is NOT defined)
```

Then if variable is empty, use `GOTO` like

```
:retry
set /P MyVar=test py:
IF "%MyVar%"=="" ( 
    ECHO MyVar is NOT defined
    GOTO retry
) ELSE (
    ECHO MyVar IS defined
)
```

Must read:
http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_defined.php
http://ss64.com/nt/if.html http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html
`HELP IF` and `HELP GOTO` in `cmd`